# Save gameplay in localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have [**this code**](http://jsfiddle.net/dJEk7/1/):

```
Storage.prototype.setObj = function(key, obj) {
    return this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj))
}
Storage.prototype.getObj = function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key))
}
function onReady() {
    if (localStorage["piecesArray"]) {
        piecesArray = new Array();
        piecesArray.length = 0; 
        piecesArray = localStorage.getObj("piecesArray");
    } else {
        piecesArray = new Array();
    }
    can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = can.getContext('2d');         
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = onImage1Load;
    img.src = "http://www.niagaraparks.com/images/wallpaper/niagarafalls_640x480.jpg";
}
```

And I want to save the game state in `localStorage`, and after refreshing the page I want to refresh the game state.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You were setting an `window.onload` inside the JSFiddle's `window.load` wrapper. Removed it from your fiddle, use the `No wrap - in <body>` at top left of the page.

Comment: Does localStorage have a `getObj` method ?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Why are you answering by editing his JSFiddle link in his own question instead of making a new answer and posting yours here x) ?

Comment: @RelevantUsername That was a problem with the fiddle, not an answer. Read the paragraphs after the code and the question title. `=]`

Comment: How many people are editing his question? haha

Comment: @blachawk According to [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16485592/revisions) it'd be 3 editors. I believe there are no remaining typos left now. `=]`

Comment: @adeneo look at his fiddle, its a custom function to store and get objects

Comment: I've added the custom storage methods to the question to reduce confusion and one last grammar fix.

Comment: I still don't get it, you have an array, you stringify that and save it, and when you bring it back you parse into an object. The original array and the object you got from localstorage don't match, and even if you get the object you still run the scrambling of the array etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there's two problems I noticed in your fiddle.

First, you have a function you're calling that isn't defined, so you're not running the `setObj` function.

```
if (drawHighlight) highlightRect(drawX, drawY);
// liczymy kliknięcia
clickCounter(); // This function doesn't exist
localStorage.setObj("piecesArray", piecesArray);
```

I added in a dummy `clickCounter` function for you that doesn't do anything.

Additionally, you were loading up the `piecesArray` from local storage, but then just overwriting it anyway. Once your image loads, you need to check to see if you already have a `piecesArray`. I did that like this:

```
function onImage1Load() {
    var r;
    if (piecesArray.length === 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                r = new Rectangle(i * blockSize, j * blockSize, i * blockSize + blockSize, j * blockSize + blockSize);
                piecesArray.push(r);
            }
        }

        scrambleArray(piecesArray, 30);
    }
    drawImage();

}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJEk7/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Set Item with

```
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(yourValue));
```

and get Item with

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(yourValue));
```

If no value stored in localStorage, you will get 'null'. So you can use:

```
var pieces = localStorage.getItem('piecesArray');
if (pieces) {
    piecesArray = JSON.parse(pieces);
} else {
    piecesArray = new Array();
}
```

Comment: no this isn't the solution. He's using specific getObj and setObj functions to set and get objects. Look at his fiddle.

Comment: @Piszu you must save your piecesArray at runtime with localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(piecesArray)); I use this without any problems

Comment: @RwamDev please look at his fiddle, he does!

Comment: @RwamDev - i don't get it :X

Comment: @Piszu you're better off ignoring this answer.. its not a solution at all.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen this only now.